# SFTP connection with Windows 2008 server . How to prevent trust on first use (TOFU) request?

Tags: security, ssh, windows-server-2008, sftp

We have a windows server with SFTP connection via SSH.

It has to be super secure, but when we or other users connect, they get question for trust on first use.

How can we realise more trust? Do we need public/private key authentication? (now is just password and user). SSH does not have anything to do with certificates right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users are asked if they trust server's key. This question is asked by the client software.
To prevent the question you need to deliver server's public key to the client somehow (before first connection) and add it to the list of trusted keys, maintained by the client software used by the client.

SSL/TLS also uses the scheme where the server authenticates itself using the public key (usually, as there exist alternative schemes). That key is wrapped into the X.509 certificate. All clients know how to validate the certificate and trust (or not trust) the key because X.509 infrastructure is hierarchical and there exist lists of trusted root and CA certificates on the client side.

In SSH, however, it is different - SSH keys don't form infrastructure and each key must be trusted explicitly. The client provides his public key to the server (if it wants to use public-key authentication, and the server authenticates itself also by providing the public key. There's no way for SSH client to validate the key other than to compare it explicitly with the keys in its trust list that the administrator forms by hand (or copies from another computer).

Comment: @user2897757 proper way to thank on StackOverflow network is to upvote the answer. If your question in whole is answered in some particular answer, you need to mark that answer as accepted to let others know that the question has been answered. The checkmark is located under the vote buttons.